# SupportMapFragment return null on Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps-api-2

I move my application eclipse to android studio. My code works perfect on Eclipse but on Android studio

```
mapView = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

return null
my xml is here

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >
   <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adMob"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_unit_id" />
   <fragment
  android:id="@+id/map"        
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"        
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"        
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

why it return null?

I searched and `compileSdkVersion 21` cause it. But if I change it 19 still return null

Comment: ... so keep `compileSdkVersion` at `21`?

Comment: yeah i keep it at 21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getMap()` is not guaranteed to return a map instance. Use `getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback)` where the callback will be invoked once the map is ready and you're guaranteed it won't be `null`. This is available since Google Play Services library v6.5.

When using this approach get rid of your `mapView` variable, the callback will receive a map reference anyway. Also note that `SupportMapFragment` is not `MapView` is not `GoogleMap` (I'm referring to the misnamed variable here, be careful.).

**EDIT:** Suggested solution:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

  SupportMapFragment mMapFragment;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mMapFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    // etc.
  }

  public void doSomethingWithMap() {
    mMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
      @Override
      public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        // do whatever you need with the map
      }
    });
  }
}
```

The point is when you need to access the map, you ask the fragment for it, and it will be delivered to you via a callback.

Comment: thanks for answer but how to I use getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback) bind java class to xml for fragment?

Comment: I found this  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map but now problem i have setOnMarkerClickListener(this); and setOnMapClickListener(this); how to use them ?previosly i used them with GoogleMaps object

Comment: See `onMapReady(GoogleMap)`. Now you have a google map object. Do the settings here.

Comment: thanks. I trying your code but this times gives error about getSupportFragmentManager(). can not resolve method

Comment: It's the same method call as you used.

Comment: i did cast and error gone  mMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);